# ADDS - Supply value for the following parameters

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to install an ADDSForest via PowerShell. I'd like to it be fully automatic, but get the following message.

```
cmdlet Install-ADDSForest at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
DomainName:
```

Here is my code:

```
 Import-Module ADDSDeployment
 Install-ADDSForest -CreateDnsDelegation:$true ` 
-DatabasePath "C:\Windows\NTDS" ` 
-DomainMode "Win2012" ` 
-DomainName "Swag"` 
-SafeModeAdministratorPassword "Test01" `
-DomainNetbiosName "Test biosname" ` 
-ForestMode "Win2012" ` 
-InstallDns:$true ` 
-LogPath "C:\Windows\NTDS" ` 
-NoRebootOnCompletion:$false ` 
-SysvolPath "C:\Windows\SYSVOL" `
-Force:$true
```

As you can see, it is asking for a supply value for the DomainName, whilst I already gave it. How can I edit my code so that I dont have to enter a supply value that I already gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra space after the `` ` `` following the `-DomainMode` argument.

Use a splatting table instead of `` ` ``:

```
$InstallForestParams = @{
    CreateDnsDelegation = $true
    DatabasePath = "C:\Windows\NTDS" 
    DomainMode = "Win2012"
    DomainName = "Swag"
    SafeModeAdministratorPassword = "Test01" 
    DomainNetbiosName = "Test biosname"
    ForestMode = "Win2012"
    InstallDns = $true
    LogPath = "C:\Windows\NTDS"
    NoRebootOnCompletion = $false
    SysvolPath = "C:\Windows\SYSVOL"
    Force = $true
}

Install-ADDSForest @InstallForestParams
```